# Extra left and right padding on scaled ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, padding

I have this layout:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:padding="6dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_favourites"
            android:textColor="@color/welcome_textcolor"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_detect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/detect_btn" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_detect"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like in the eclipse graphical layout

[image]

If you notice there's unwanted padding to the left and right side of the two ImageViews on the right.
How do I remove that without

- specifying absolute width/height for the images (I want them to alignTop and alignBottom from the TextView on the left)
- having negative margins/paddings (that will have to be adjusted depending on screen density)

I already set the adjustViewBounds attribute to true as you can see in the code, but apparently it only fixes the unwanted padding on the top and bottom of the ImageViews, so it's basically useless here.

Additional info:
The images are large -- like way larger than what is displayed. But they are being scaled correctly as you can see here. And no, they don't have transparent padding in them.

Comment: Curious: have you tried on an actual device yet? The graphical editor can be a bit buggy at times.

Comment: yes, and it looks the same as in the eclipse preview.

Comment: Can you try removing the alignTop and alignBottom attributes? They shouldn't be relevant with the centerVertical attribute in place, and might be conflicting.

Comment: they are relevant, because i want the height to be relative to the size of the TextView on the left. unless there's another way to do that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot your images were larger; just trying to narrow things down. Perhaps try a horizontal LinearLayout with the textview weight set to 1?

Comment: can you expand on that suggestion? what weight would i use on my ImageViews then?

Comment: Hmm, nevermind, that would require you to either have a fixed or max height for your images. Is resizing the assets themselves not an option? That would be better for both quality and performance.

Comment: yes, that would solve it. i'm just curious as to why the padding is there, and why adjustViewBounds=true doesn't work for removing that annoying horizontal padding.

Comment: I'm aware that using a properly-sized image would solve the issue, but this would lead to a deeper question -- for example i want the two images to actually touch each other. Do i need to have exact sizes for my images? across all densities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LinerLayout inside RelativeLayot like this for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/favorites_top_bar" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:padding="6dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_artword_detected"
            android:textColor="@color/welcome_textcolor"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/artwork_detected_text"
        android:background="@color/favorites_top_bar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_detect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/detect_btn" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="6dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </View>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just made some very slight changes, but that worked! now I have to know, why does this work and my original implementation doesn't?

Comment: Interesting question. I think the whole thing in a different layouts rendering work. In my case it's intuitive understanding through experience. Any way I do not know the exact answer to this question. In my free time I will try to view the source code for understanding this. But it's really interesting question and maybe someone else answer it.

Comment: you're saying LinearLayout and RelativeLayout treats its children ImageViews differently.. weird, but it looks like that's what is happening here.